# Apache2 not starting, guess bad config file

Tags: apache-http-server, ruby-on-rails, passenger

this is the problem starting apache2:

```
apache2 -k restart
[Wed May 28 11:53:07 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

want to run apache2 with passenger and ruby on rails on debian

help needed

Answer (score 0):

Something else is bound to port 80.

If you do

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep :80
```

then the output will give you some idea as to what process is bound to that port.  The last column of the output gives the process name and PID:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1456/apache2
```

Comment: netstat -nlp | grep :80                     tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      18651/apache2

Comment: So you have an apache process running already that's bound to that port, and for some reason it isn't dying in the normal way.  Try `sudo kill 18651`, make sure it's gone, then try starting it again.

Answer (score 0):

> guess bad config file

You can specifically test your configuration file using [apachectl configtest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html)

> [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

This is only a warning. It may indicate that your configuration file needs attention. It wouldn't stop Apache starting up.

> (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down

Some existing program is using socket 80 (binding to port 80) - you must identify that (See Flup's answer) and resolve the conflict. One way would be to configure Apache to listen on a different port number (e.g. 81 or 8080).

Comment: could you help me configuring the server, if I give you the adress, username and password?

Comment: @Joern: That proposition looks like the sort of open-ended unpaid can of worms I probably wouldn't enjoy very much. I'm sure plenty of people (including me) will be happy to use this Q&A site to help you  to do what you want with the expectation you are willing to put in significant learning effort yourself. If you want to pay someone to be your sysadmin, there's other websites for that.